# findViewById Error cant find id in XML

Tags: java, android, xml, findviewbyid

I cant find out why my `findViewById` is not linking to the XML file and it is driving me nuts.  The is is in the XML file but it is still not Finding it in the java `MainActivity` file.

here is my XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editCentimeters"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="27sp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editInches"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textCentimeters"
    android:ems="5" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonConvert"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editInches"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="98dp"
    android:text="@string/convert" />
```

And here is my Java

```
EditText etCentimeters = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editCentimeters);
Button buttonConvert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonConvert);
```

Comment: put your onCreate() code

Comment: Paste your Activity code.

Comment: will u pls post your code.

Comment: just try to clean the project once. the R.java file will be generated and everything should work fine if you have that view id in the layout file.

Comment: You also missing end close EditText "editCentimeters"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was facing the same issue. Just  comment out the line which is throwing the error & BUILD the project once. Intellisense (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd>) then will show you the IDs.

Answer (score 0):

use `setContentView(R.layout.main);` at the onCreate of your Activity

Answer (score 0):

You need to take care of 2 things here:-

```
EditText etCentimeters = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editCentimeters);
Button buttonConvert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonConvert);
```

Firstly, the above code should be present in the `onCreate()` method.

And next, you need to place that code snippet below this line in the `onCreate()` method, not before it.(I'm assuming that the `setContentView` is already present, if not, add that)

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refresh project.
And also check ur `setContentView(R.layout.YOURLAYOUT_NAME)` in Your activity.
Make sure that u are using ur code in activity.

Answer (score 0):

Just clean & build in order to find the ID.

Comment: kindly consider adding more information in your answer

Comment: ? Sometimes just cleaning and building updates the layouts and IDs. No more, is simple.

Answer (score 0):

Clean & build didn't work for me. I had to restart Android Studio.