# how to add a missing android manifest file

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-manifest

My android  manifest file was deleted, I have been looking around and have not found how solution on stack overflow, does anyone have a suggestion?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is R only not found for `one_button_ET` or are there others? Also why do some `findViewById` have double ()?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot read packageName from AndroidManifest.xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32447683/cannot-read-packagename-from-androidmanifest-xml)

Comment: And maybe you wanna look this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18871959/findviewbyid-error-cant-find-id-in-xml

Comment: @Trozza all of the ImageButtons in the code I attached are affected, the double parenthesis were from autofill, they don't seem to be causing this.

Comment: @B.Kaan this dosen't work because of the android manifest error I mentioned

Comment: @MortaddaJafar it looks like my android manifest was deleted, where/ how do I create a new one?

Comment: Can you not just create a new one using a text editor and place it in your `app->src->main` folder, then clean and rebuild? That should work...

Comment: @DigitalNinja what needs to be in the manifest file?

Comment: @Lontronix That strictly depends on your app... https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html

Comment: Suppose If you have .apk file then decompile that file from this site http://www.javadecompilers.com/ and find that manifest file from the source.

Comment: Try this , you might recover your Manifest file , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23198486/recovery-the-deleted-xml-file-from-app-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can revert your action back by following 3 simple steps in Android Studio :
1) Click on VCS menu first [image: VCS]

2) Than click on Local History option.
[image]

3) Search for your deleting manifest file action and revert it back.For example:
[image: Click revert]